# Openshift: Configuring custom DH parameters with a 1024-bit prime

Tags: ssl, jboss, oauth-2.0, openshift, reddit

I am running a basic Java EE web application on Red Hat's Openshift cloud that wants connect with Reddit's api via oauth2. I have done the same for LinkedIn and every works well there but with Reddit I get the following error:

```
2014/06/12 05:02:06,992 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.8.212.1-8080-2) javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair

2014/06/12 05:02:07,319 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.8.212.1-8080-2)   ... 48 more
2014/06/12 05:02:07,326 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.8.212.1-8080-2) Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
2014/06/12 05:02:07,338 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.8.212.1-8080-2)   at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyPairGenerator.initialize(DHKeyPairGenerator.java:120)
2014/06/12 05:02:07,344 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.8.212.1-8080-2)   at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.initialize(KeyPairGenerator.java:658)
2014/06/12 05:02:07,351 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.8.212.1-8080-2)   at sun.security.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:127)
2014/06/12 05:02:07,359 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.8.212.1-8080-2)   ... 55 more
```

I couldn't find an answer elsewhere in stackoverflow, although I have seen similar issues with other people. It seems that I need to change the mod_ssl parameters in JBoss's configuration files to support custom DH parameters with a 1024-bit prime. Can someone help me fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While someone here may be able to provide a better answer/workaround... If you need the mod_ssl parameters changed on the cartridge I would recommend opening an issue on the repo itself here: https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap or opening a bug on bugzilla.redhat.com.